# Do cells not grow during mitotic S phase (synthesis phase of interphase of the cell cycle)?

Tags: cell-biology, molecular-genetics

Both these links mention cell growth during G1 and G2 phase, but not during synthesis phase (only DNA replication is mentioned). Is replication all that happens and is there no cell growth during S phase?

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/interphase

https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/Book%3A_General_Biology_(Boundless)/10%3A_Cell_Reproduction/10.02%3A_The_Cell_Cycle/10.2A%3A_Interphase

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. This will help you ask good questions and avoid some of the pitfalls that new users can experience using this site.

Comment: Also note that each post should only have one question, so I've focused on the question of "growth" as that seems the most central to what you are asking. There are of course many other processes that occur throughout the cell cycle, but that is beyond the scope of a single question (or this site in general) so I've removed those.

Answer (score 2):

By growth I'm assuming you mean something like an increase in cell mass/volume.

This can likely vary depending on the organism and cell type (biology is riddled with exceptions), but in budding yeast (*Saccharomyces cerevisiae*) cell mass increases during mitotic S phase<sup>1</sup>.

The following is a quote from the introduction to reference 1:

> Typical pie chart representation of the cell cycle (Figure 1A) stresses the discontinuous events that have to take place only once per cell cycle (i.e., S and M phases), but fails to show that proliferating somatic cells are continuously increasing in their mass throughout the cell cycle (Figure 1B). As pointed out as early as 1971 by Mitchinson<sup>2</sup>, the “continuous events of the growth cycle” (i.e., increase in cell mass) and the “discontinuous events of the DNA division cycle” (i.e., DNA replication, mitosis, and cell division) need to be tightly coordinated in order to maintain cell size homeostasis.
>
> [image]
>
> #### Main Events That Occur during the Yeast Cell Cycle
>
> (A) General representation of the cell cycle showing the discontinuous events that have to take place only once per cell cycle, namely the S phase and the M phase, spaced with G1 and G2 phases that allow increase of the cell size before DNA replication and cell division, respectively.
>
> (B) During the dynamics of the cell cycle, RNA and proteins increase exponentially, while the DNA content show a typical doubling amount until the cell divides to generate a newborn daughter. From G1 to M phases, the cell increases continuously in mass.

#### References:

1. [Barberis, M., Klipp, E., Vanoni, M., & Alberghina, L. (2007). Cell size at S phase initiation: an emergent property of the G1/S network. PLoS computational biology, 3(4), e64.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1851985/)
2. [Mitchison, J. M. (1971). Biology of the cell cycle.](https://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search.do?recordID=US201300474975)

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome! If this [addressed your problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. Once you have ≥15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.